# "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute"

Tags: node.js, cookies, stripe-payments

Hey I am working on a stripe project which redirect the user to stripe portal for payment but got stuck when I got this error :

Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute?

Here is my server.js in which I also has set the header :

```
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const uuid = require("uuid")
// Config dotev
require('dotenv').config({
    path: './config/config.env'
})
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)


const app = express()

// Connect to database
connectDB();

// body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

//header
app.use((req,res) => {
    res.cookie('cookie', 'value', { sameSite: 'none', secure: true })
})

// Load routes
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth.route')
const stripeRouter = require('./routes/stripe.route')

// Dev Logginf Middleware
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(cors({
        origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL
    }))
    app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

// Use Routes
app.use('/api', authRouter)
app.use('/api' , stripeRouter)

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
        msg: "Page not founded"
    })
})




const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

As per Stripe support >>>> In February 2020, Google released Chrome 80 and began rolling out new cookie behavior. Details of this change and Google’s rollout plans are available at https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site.

This change requires cross-site cookies to explicitly declare themselves with the SameSite attribute. Cookies that do not do this will result in a Chrome warning in the developer console and being ignored (not sent with any applicable requests).

All Stripe products (i.e. Elements, Checkout, etc.) that use cookies accessible across sites have been updated and will function the same as before the Chrome 80 release.

However, there may still be some cookies set by the Stripe Dashboard, Support Site, or home page that will trigger the Chrome warning on other sites that include the Stripe.js library. We will continue to work at reducing/eliminating these, but these remaining instances do not impact any functionality of Stripe products and only result in a benign warning in the developer console.